# Circleci passing a docker image in workflow jobs

Tags: circleci

Is it possible to pass docker images built in earlier job in circle ci

example

```
jobs:
    build:
         steps:
        - checkout
            // build image

    deploy:
         steps:
        - deploy earlier image
```

i cant see how i can access the image without rebuilding it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each job can run on a different host, so to share the image you would need to push it to a registry from the job that builds it.

To reference the same job that was pushed you'll need an identifier that is known ahead of time. A good example of this is the `CIRCLE_SHA1` environment variable. You can use this variable as the image tag

```
jobs:
  build:
    machine: true
    steps:
      ...
      - run: |
          docker build -t repo/app:$CIRCLE_SHA1 .
          docker push repo/app:$CIRCLE_SHA1

  test:
    docker:
      - image: repo/app:$CIRCLE_SHA1
    steps:
      ...
```

Comment: How can this be achieved?

Comment: Setup a repo in a docker registry (Docker Hub, ECR, GCR, or quay.io are popular). Then `docker push` to that repo. Configure downstream jobs with the image you pushed.

Comment: I understand. But if job 1 pushes an image `saw303/image:123` how can I pass the tag information to the depending job 2 to tell it to pull the image with the tag `123`?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think the idea is to use an identified that is already known ahead of time, instead of passing the tag around.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this by persisting the image to a workspace and then attaching the workspace when you want to deploy it. See CircleCI's workspace documentation here: https://circleci.com/docs/workspaces